# Como habilitar cross-origin no tomcat?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, tomcat, servlet

Basicamente preciso habilitar o *Cross-Origin* no meu *Tomcat* 8.5. Quero saber a forma correta de fazer isso e quais são os riscos?

Comment: Veja se isto ajuda: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter